# How do I make an Android phone play sounds remotely?

Tags: audio, remote-control

I'm doing a Lego EV3 robot for a project. It needs to play sounds (like a soundboard app on a phone, but triggered remotely). Sadly, the speaker on the EV3 brick is too quiet for this.

I got the idea to use my old phone connected to a Bluetooth speaker. I want to hold my phone in my hand and with that phone, I want to make my other phone play short MP3 files. Without any wired connection. Sadly, I can't find any apps that already do this and I have no programming experience.

Is there another way to remotely trigger playback of a sound file stored on the phone? I'm okay with rooting the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [AirDroid](https://www.airdroid.com/)? It's very easy to use!

Or you can try something like [LogMeIn](https://www.logmein.com/). It's a cloud-based remote connectivity service a bit more complicated to set up.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [TeamViewer Host](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.host.market) on your remote phone and [TeamViewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile) on your regular phone. Setup is straightforward.

I use this for a similar purpose. I have a cheap Chinese surveillance cam which sends me an alert to my phone when an intrusion is detected. I want to play a loud sound when an intruder is detected, but unfortunately the camera built-in speaker power is too low. I had the idea of connecting an old phone to a set of speakers, then remotely controlling it to open the audio player and play a sound. I can easily accomplish this "manually" with this setup while I try to figure out how to accomplish this in a more automated way.